# Do convolutional neural networks also have recurrent connections?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, recurrent-neural-networks, comparison

I asked my self this simple question while reading ["Comment Abuse Classification with Deep Learning"](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs224n/reports/2762092.pdf) by Chu and Jue. Indeed, they say at the end of the that

> *It is clear that RNNs, specifically LSTMs, and CNNs are state-of-the-art  architectures for sentiment analysis*

To my mind CNNs were only neurons arranged so that they correspond to overlapping regions when paving the input field. It wasn't that recurrent at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. I think you are just misinterpreting the part of the sentence ('specifically LSTMs'). LSTMs are an example of a popular type of RNN.
RNNs and CNNs are different architectures but they can be used together.

Here is another sentence with the same structure:

> It is clear than dogs, specifically corgis, and cats are very common in online memes.

[image: A cat and a corgi]

Answer (score 3):

Both CNN and RNN fall into the super set of neural networks,however applications of the two matters.

So to branch them off in terms of applications,

> I would say CNN’s are mainly used for vision related applications,
>   whereas, RNN’s are mainly used for language processing applications.

You can refer to these links for further details.

[Comparative Study of CNN and RNN for Natural Language Processing](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.01923)

[How are recurrent neural networks different from convolutional neural networks?](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/)
*The unreasonable effectiveness of Recurrent Neural Networks*

Hope this can give you a glimpse!